# Core Bluetooth Function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bluetooth, sdk

so I have been searching the web for the past couple days and still can't seem to find a solution that works. I'm running Core Bluetooth and am attempting to get data from an Arduino. Here's the code:

```
//Reading Bluetooth Data
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
    let data = characteristic.value
    if let str:String = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        self.delegate?.serialDidReceiveString(str)
        print(str)
    }
}
```

I could see the incoming data using `print(str)` without an issue, but how in the world would I transfer this received data to another swift file and eventually display it onto a UILabel? Every time I try to use `str` outside the function, Xcode keeps telling be "expected declaration". My attempt of the delegate is a follows:

```
protocol BluetoothSerialDelegate {
    func serialDidReceiveString(message: String)
}
extension BluetoothSerialDelegate {
    func serialDidReceiveString(message: String) {}
}
```

With this variable defined within the class that the function is located in. `var delegate: BluetoothSerialDelegate!` Though I get no errors, when I call

```
func serialDidReceiveString(message: String) {
        Label.text! = message
        print(message)
    }
```

Inside the ViewController, I am unable to see the data like I did when it called from the initial function. What could the issue possibly be? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the string in your h file so you have a global variable.    Or you could just save it user User Defaults, that would make it easy to access from another file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a delegate...why  not use it? In the class you want to display the data in, conform to your delegate, and implement the delegate method `serialDidReceiveString:`. Then, when the data is received, the delegate method will be called in the other view, and you can then update your label.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, this is my first project in Swift and a lot of the information was brought together by different forums. Would you please explain to me in greater detail how I would go about doing this with the delegate method? I have attempted it but found that once the function is called though the other swift file, it no longer displays the received data. Also, if you would like, I would be more then happy to share the code with you. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not very helpful to link to your whole project. It can't be indexed and other people won't be able to see it in the future. Please add the relevant bits of code to your question as an edit.

Comment: Okay, I just edited in the entire scope of what was done.

Comment: Question has been answered here for those with the same issue.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688478/retrieving-function-data?noredirect=1#comment60971482_36688478