# Retrieving Function Data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bluetooth, sdk

I have a function whose data I would really like to retrieve.

Within the brackets, I am able to print out the value `DecodedData`.

However, if I was to put `print(DecodedData)` just outside the function, Xcode tells me that 'Expected declaration' how would I be able to have `DecodedData` accessible throughout the file?

I've tried using the delegate method with no success, is there any other way? and if so, how would I go about doing it?

```
var DecodedData = ""
//Reading Bluetooth Data
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    if let data = characteristic.value {
        DecodedData = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    }

    print(DecodedData)
}
```

How would I go about having the variable `DecodedData` available throughout different Swift files?

Comment: where exactly do you put another `print(DecodedData)` line

Comment: Right after the last curly bracket.

Comment: this seems like not a right place to interact with variables. Could you copy the hole code of your class?

Comment: sahil's first solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create static variable in the class and use it any other swift file.

```
class YourClass {
static var DecodedData: String = ""
 ...


 func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

   if let data = characteristic.value {
     YourClass.DecodedData = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
   }
print(YourClass.DecodedData)
}
}
```

or you can create singleton object of yourclas.

```
class YourClass {

 static let singletonInstance = YourClass()

 var DecodedData: String = ""

 private init() {
 }

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

if let data = characteristic.value {
  self.DecodedData = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
}
}
}
```

and  in other class you can use by singleton object.

Comment: Thank you, good sir! Your first solution works like a champion!

Comment: Oops I almost forgot;)